# how to handle file not found, when reading a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm reading a string from file by a shell script.
it goes like this:

```
count = 0
while read LINE
do
    count++
    if [ "$LINE" == "NONE" ]
    then
       echo "state is NONE"
    else
       if [ "$LINE" == "PLAYING" ]
       then
           echo "state is PLAYING"
       fi
    fi
done<$FILENAME
```

this is what I read from the file, and how I handle it, now I want to do something else if the file not found, is there anyway to do that?
for example:

```
if[ file not found]
then
   do something
fi
```

Comment: This is not a syntactically correct bash script, have you ran it yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if [ -f path_to_file ]
then
  echo "file was found"
else
  echo "file was not found"
fi
```

Comment: There needs to be a space after `if`.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better start you script with a condition like:

```
if [ ! -f /your/file ]; then
    echo "file not found"
else
    ...
    proceed with your `while`, etc.
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Preferring this negated condition check if you goal is to have the rather short error handling routine first and the complex (longer!) parts of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to read the file, then maybe you should test to see if the file exists, *and* if you have read access:

```
if [[ ! -f $FILENAME ]] || [[ ! -r $FILENAME ]]
then
    # do stuff
fi
```

The `-f` tests to see if `$FILENAME` is a regular file, `-r` tests to see if you (the current user) has read access.